# Is this a commonly used expression, "awfully hard to do"?

Tags: pronunciation

could some please help to listen what the professor is [saying](https://youtu.be/XPGaTGTD7o0?t=476)?

it sounds like **xx awfully** hard to do.

is this a commonly used expression?

Comment: It sounds like "That seem awfully hard to do". I don't think the professor is a native English speaker; he should have said _seems_. _Awfully_ is a colloquial way of saying _very_; it's commonly used in informal speech.

Comment: @KateBunting thank you so much. You've solved my problem! plz mv it to answer.

Comment: @KateBunting Maybe he was referring to a set of some tgings that is being rendered as a singular unit in his opinion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds as though he is saying "That seem awfully hard to do". (It should be *seems*, but I don't think the professor is a native speaker of English.)

*Awfully* is just a colloquial way of saying *very*, which is commonly used in informal speech. https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/awfully